# strcat not working, string is formatted each time

Tags: c, string, while-loop, strcat

This is part of a larger program, but I found it to be super buggy and totally incorrect
This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char term_command[500];
    char fname[20];
    FILE *fp;

    //open list of files
    fp = fopen("list.txt", "r+");

    //check 
    if(fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR OPENING FILE list.txt\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(term_command, "sort -m -n ");
    printf("com: %s\n", term_command);

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", fname) != EOF){
        printf("com: %s\n", term_command);
        if(strcmp(fname, "list.txt") != 0){
            strcat(term_command, fname);
            strcat(term_command, " ");
        }
    }

    strcat(term_command, "-o all_sorted.txt");
    printf("com1: %s\n", term_command);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output I get

```
com: sort -m -n 
com: 
com: 
com: 
com: 
com: 
com: 
com: -o all_sorted.txt
```

I don't understand why the string fname isn't attached to the term_command string, and why the term_command string is empty as soon as I get in the while loop.

edit:

This is an example of file "list.txt"

```
f0
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
list.txt
```

I changed fname size to 20 but nothing changed

Comment: Is `term_command` memory properly allocated ?

Comment: for the sake of simplicity I didn't allocate it dynamcally, I just went for "char term_command[500];"

Comment: `while(fscanf(fp, "%s", fname) != EOF){` - `fname` only has space for 2 chars + EOS.

Comment: The fscanf() may be overwriting beyond the 3 char's allocated for fname, with unpredictable effects.

Comment: I know it's not a safe way to allocate the string, but I was trying to isolate the problem in a controlled environment, where I'm sure all fnames have length < 3 (except for list.txt which I didn't account for, so I increased string size to 20, but nothing changed)

Comment: Works ok on my pc (VisualStudio 2013). And on ideone (modified to use stdin): https://ideone.com/k8Oclg

Comment: Still not working on my PC.. I can't understand why. I'll try on a different machine as soon as I get a chance

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Don't try on a different machine. Debug it on your current machine.

Comment: You can put a sentinel variable with a defined between the two arrays and see whether tit's overwritten.    `char term_command[500];char guard;
    char fname[20]; guard = 42; ` and later  `if (guard != 42) panik`

Comment: Turns out it was a problem caused by the text editor. I don't know why, but it stopped saving the changes I made to the program. So.. other than the wrong memory allocation for fname, everything else turned out to be working. Thanks guys!